# magento clear cache programatically for a particular product using product id

Tags: magento, caching

As my question says I want to remove cache `(FULL PAGE CACHE)` for a particular product using product id. Is that possible ?

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684236/magento-disable-cache-for-price-block/28167527#28167527

Answer (score 1):

Every model has cleanModelCache() method that clean the cache using the model tags.

See Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::cleanModelCache()

```
public function cleanModelCache()
    {
        $tags = $this->getCacheIdTagsWithCategories();
        if ($tags !== false) {
            Mage::app()->cleanCache($tags);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

`Mage::app()->cleanCache($tags);` is what cleans the cache.

If you want to clean using only the product ID you'll need to load at least the categories associated to that product and built the cacha tag list as for the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getCacheIdTagsWithCategories()`

```
public function getCacheIdTagsWithCategories()
    {
        $tags = $this->getCacheTags();
        $affectedCategoryIds = $this->_getResource()->getCategoryIdsWithAnchors($this);
        foreach ($affectedCategoryIds as $categoryId) {
            $tags[] = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG.'_'.$categoryId;
        }
        return $tags;
    }
```